# How to count no of days id is having positive balance and negative balance in SAS

Tags: sas

My data is as following:

```
id   balance  date
1     10      02Mar2018
1     12      05Mar2018
1    -15      07Mar2018
1     14      14Mar2018
1    -25      25Mar2018
```

Now i want the number of days id 1 was in positive bal and number of days the id was in negative bal in a march month.
For example no of days in positive will be calculated as following 01mar to 06 mar as first negative entry came on 07Mar so that 6 days.
Then again it went on positive bal on 14 to ,24 that 11 days
so in total it was 6+11=17 days in positive.

And similarly for negative bal.

I tried using following code:

```
DATA B;
SET A ;
BY ID;
IF FIRST.ID THEN Y=DATE;
RETAIN Y;
ELSE Y=INTCK('day',DATE,Y);
RUN;
```

But couldn't get the exact results.
Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: You will need separate variables such as `pos_days` and `neg_days` to accumulate the `INTCK`s with in a month.  You will also need a bit of logic to detect month changing, handling 1st of month to 1st record in month, last record in month to last day in month.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is sorted by `id` and `date`.

First do a 'look-ahead' merge (to get the next date) :

```
data lookahead ;
  merge have
        have (firstobs=2 rename=(date=nextdate id=nextid)) ;

  if id ^= nextid then call missing(nextdate) ;
  drop nextid ;
run ;

/* data now looks like this */
id   balance  date      nextdate
1     10      02Mar2018 05Mar2018
1     12      05Mar2018 07Mar2018
1    -15      07Mar2018 14Mar2018
1     14      14Mar2018 25Mar2018
1    -25      25Mar2018
```

Then, expand out the missing dates, dealing with instances where the first date per id isn't the 1st of a month, and the last record per id isn't the last day of the month :

```
data expand ;
  set lookahead (rename=(date=thisdate)) ;
  by id ;

  if first.id and day(thisdate) ^= 1 then do ;
    /* loop from 1st of month to day before date, output new record for each date */
    do date = intnx('month',thisdate,0,'b') to thisdate - 1 ;
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;

  /* output the input record */
  date = thisdate ; output ;

  /* output dates up to the next date */
  if nextdate > thisdate + 1 then do ;
    do date = thisdate + 1 to nextdate - 1 ;
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;
  else 
  /* last record for id, loop to end of month */
  if missing(nextdate) and thisdate ^= intnx('month',thisdate,0,'end') then do ;
    do date = thisdate + 1 to intnx('month',thisdate,0,'end') ;
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;

  drop thisdate nextdate ;
  format date date9. ;
run ;

/* data now looks like this */
id   balance  date      
1     10      01Mar2018
1     10      02Mar2018
1     10      03Mar2018
1     10      04Mar2018 
1     12      05Mar2018
1     12      06Mar2018 
1    -15      07Mar2018
1    -15      08Mar2018
... etc ...
1    -15      13Mar2018 
1     14      14Mar2018
1     14      15Mar2018
... etc ... 
1     14      24Mar2018
1    -25      25Mar2018
... etc ...
1    -25      31Mar2018
```

It should now be relatively easily to flag the values accordingly, and count them up per id/month.

Comment: It will be helpfull when i have only one id but in my case i have multiple ids and this needs to calculated for all the ids so i am not sure how i can do a look ahead on the basis of multiple ids.

Comment: just saw that you are comparing this as well.I think this should work.